# Request with POST Body consisting of Key/Value pairs AND an Object (for Swagger) Parameters

Tags: javascript, json, rest, xmlhttprequest, swagger

Until now i have used `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` to pass key value pairs in the body and if i had to pass an object `applicaton/json`

```
post:
  tags:
    - "users"
  summary: "Create User"
  operationId: "createUser"
  consumes:
  - "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
  parameters:
  - name: "username"
    in: "formData"
    description: "Name of User"
    required: true
    type: "string"
  - name: "email"
    in: "formData"
    description: "Email"
    required: true
    type: "string"
```

now i want to add an object:

```
{
  "member":{
   "name":string,
   "email":string
 }
}
```

which i described in the defintions:

```
definitions:
  member:
    type:"object"
    properties:
      name:
        type: string
      email:
        type: string
```

how can this be done in swagger?

here are the docs: https://swagger.io/docs/specification/describing-request-body/
but i don't understand how i can retain my normal key value pairs in the body.

Comment: Just to clarify - do you want 1) a single endpoint that can accept `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` OR `application/json` 2) two different endpoints, one that accepts form data and another that accepts JSON; or 3) send JSON as part of form data (`application/x-www-form-urlencoded` or `multipart/mixed`) along with some other key=value pairs?

Comment: The number of endpoints does not matter... I want to pass key value pairs and an object together inside a request body. But it's about only 1 endpoint.